# Typescript: is it possible to get the primary type for a nested object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I have the following code

```js
const myObj = {
    a: {
        b: 'a/b',
    },
    c: {
        d: 'c/d',
    }
} as const

type T = ...
// T === 'a/b' | 'c/d'
```

Is is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using the answer to the linked question gives [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mbArEN).